# Meteor, mongodb - accessing an object inside an array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Alright, so I have a collection called Polls. Inside the Polls "table" there is an attribute called `choiceObjects` which is an array of objects. Each object inside this array has its own attributes. What I need to do is update one of the attributes there. Ill give you a screen shot so you can better visualise what Im talking about

[image]

As you can see the choice objects have attributes like body, country etc. There is another attribute called pollid which is set to optional and therefore you cant see it right now. I need to update this `pollid` attribute now that I have acess to the `pollid`

```
Polls.update(
    { _id: pollId },
    { "$set": {  "choiceObjects": { pollid: pollId } } }
); //this is kind of what Im trying to do but this isnt right
```

Since then... I have further tried the following :

```
var selectedpoll = Polls.findOne(pollId);
    console.log(selectedpoll);

    //Polls.update( selectedpoll, {"$set"{'choiceObjects.$.pollId':pollId}},false, true );
```

but when i try that i get the error : the positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. unexpanded update: choiceObjects.$.pollId

Comment: I know the problem is in the syntax of that statement, I also dont know understand how - in the set command im just putting in choiceObjects but it is obviously an array. so... yeah

Comment: Did you try this line of code `Polls.update( {_id: pollId }, { $set : { "choiceObjects.pollid": pollId }  } );`

Comment: Why would you want to insert the _id of the parent object into the array? In any case, look at the `$push` operator.

Comment: And how would you know which of the `choiceObjects` is the one that you want to update?

Comment: Michel, when the user clicks on a choice i want to increase the count and update my polls table. So thats why i want to have the pollid in all my choices.

Comment: @JeanMel This is what I was trying: var selectedpoll = Polls.findOne(pollId);
    console.log(selectedpoll);

    //Polls.update( selectedpoll, {"$set":{'choiceObjects.$.pollId':pollId}}, false, true ); //but im getting the same error as your suggested code. Error: after filtering out keys not in the schema your modifier is now empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your objective correctly, you want to update (or add) `pollid` to all objects in the `choiceObjects` array. Unfortunately `$`, `$push`, `$addToSet` only work with single elements AFAIK.

This might not be what you are looking for but one possible and very obvious way to approach this problem would be to update the entire array in the collection i.e.

```js
var choiceObjects = Polls.findOne({_id: pollId}).choiceObjects;

for (var i = 0; i < choiceObjects.length; i++) {
    choiceObjects[i].pollid = pollid;
}

Polls.update({_id: pollid}, {choiceObjects: choiceObjects});
```

Comment: This isnt exactly what I was looking for but this helped me eventually get the results I wanted. Thanks!